# Understanding return value of cacheInBackground() in EndlessAdapter

Tags: android, android-asynctask, commonsware-cwac

I am trying to follow what is going on with the `boolean` variable, `hasMoreData` with `EndlessAdapter` and why is seems to be prematurely turning `false`.

Let me start from beginning to run through what happens.  *Note:  I am using a `task` and `setRunInBackground(false);`*

I start off setting my list and setting the adapter:

```
profileList = new ArrayList<ProfileReview>();
endlessAdapter = new EndlessProfileAdapter(getActivity(), profileList);
endlessAdapter.setRunInBackground(false);
listView.setAdapter(endlessAdapter);
```

Sidenote:  Not sure if this is correct, but it seems I am setting the list with an empty adapter.

The first thing that *appears* to happen after adapter is set is the method `cacheInBackground()`, where my `profileList` size is zero, so it sets 0 as `int startPoint` when calling my `AsyncTask` where `hasMoreData` is set to `true`.  Meanwhile, in this (cache) method, `hasMoreData`  returns `true`.  *Not sure why?  Because the list is zero in size? Or because its still associated with the default value of `true`?*

In the task, it grabs first 10 items.

Then as user scrolls, the `thobber` starts spinning.  And next 10 are displayed.  `Log.d` tells me that `profileList.size()` is now 10 and `hasMoreData` is therefore false.

```
public void onItemsReady(ArrayList<ProfileReview> data) {
     profileList.addAll(data);
     endlessAdapter.onDataReady();
     hasMoreData = profileList.isEmpty();  \\ Log.'d this out
}
```

*My questions:* My list starts with 10 items, users scrolls, it grabs 10 more.  Then stops after a total of 20 items (or when `hasMoreData == false`.)  But I have many more items to pull from.  How do I keep `hasMoreData == true`? What is the trigger for this?  Obviously the trigger is list size (I think?), and why would the list size ever be 0 once it starts to grab data? (until the end of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Not sure if this is correct, but it seems I am setting the list with an empty adapter.

`EndlessAdapter` is definitely designed to start with a non-empty adapter. In fact, it is designed assuming that the user must scroll to get it to load more data. Behavior in your current approach is unspecified, and I do not recommend that approach. Please load some data, *then* populate the list once your first batch of data is ready.

> Meanwhile, in this (cache) method, hasMoreData returns true. Not sure why? Because the list is zero in size? Or because its still associated with the default value of true?

Since `EndlessAdapter` does not have a `hasMoreData` method. A search of [the source code to `EndlessAdapter`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless/blob/master/src/com/commonsware/cwac/endless/EndlessAdapter.java) turns up nothing named `hasMoreData`. Heck, the only places the word "more" appears is in comments.

A *sample app* has a `hasMoreData` value. Since you are not using this sample app, I cannot help you with random data members of random classes in your own code.

In the sample app, in `EndlessAdapterCustomTaskFragment`, I use a data member named `hasMoreData`. This is a `boolean` value, designed to be returned from `cacheInBackground()`. The responsibility of `cacheInBackground()` is to return `true` if we should continue to load data (after the current batch just loaded), `false` otherwise. In the case of this sample app, `hasMoreData` is populated by the call to `onItemsReady()`, itself triggered by `onPostExecute()` of the `AsyncTask` simulating loading some data. `hasMoreData` is set to `true` or `false` depending upon whether the `items` collection is empty, so it basically does a single load of additional data, then calls it quits.

But that is the behavior of *a sample app*. I didn't even *write* most of this class -- it came as a patch adding in support for your own data-fetching task. **Do not consider sample code to be anything more than a sample**.

Hence, *you* need to set *your* `hasMoreData` value to whatever makes sense for *your* application logic to serve whatever role *you* decided to use `hasMoreData` for. *If* `hasMoreData` has the same role in your code as it does in the sample, leave it `true` until you have determined that you are out of data, then set it `false`.

Comment: Thank you once again.  Yes, I am referring to that sample app.  As there is very little info (or real life examples) of using `EndlessAdapter` with `tasks` (and I'd like to consider myself a fairly efficient Google searcher), then I had to really use this sample as a strong basis.  You answered my questions on `hasMoreData`.  Thank you again.

Comment: @KickingLettuce: My point is that you, in your question, seem to treat `hasMoreData` as if it is some part of `EndlessAdapter`. It's not. Hence, it is incumbent upon you to explain what `hasMoreData` is in the context of your app.

Comment: Yes, I admit bad terminology.  My question I suppose had much more to do with the return variable of `cacheInBackground`.